# How to execute commands in a CGI shell script

Tags: bash, shell, command, cgi

I want to execute commands in a CGI shell script like

```
 ls -la
 ln
 pwd
 uname
 chmod
 chown
 cat
 and others ... etc ...
```

and get the output of commands in CGI and show it in CGI shell script.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

Start with `echo Content-type: text/plain; echo`. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type: text/plain
echo
echo First normal line
pwd
uname
chmod
```

Edit: beneath added, OPs wants a textfile.

Next consider what you want, A text file served by the httpd daemon?
When above script is called example, call

```
htdocs=/home/saba/http/htdocs
mkdir -p ${htdocs}
example.sh > ${htdocs}/static_output.txt
```

You can also make a html file, the content-type is not needed:

```
htdocs=/home/saba/http/htdocs
mkdir -p ${htdocs}
example.sh | grep -v "Content-type" > ${htdocs}/static_output.html
```

But now it is not valid HTML. You do not want to go escaping all code,
just add your content in a preformatted block

```
htdocs=/home/saba/http/htdocs
mkdir -p ${htdocs}
echo "<html><body><pre>" > ${htdocs}/static_output.html
example.sh | grep -v "Content-type" >> ${htdocs}/static_output.html
echo "</pre></body></html>" >> ${htdocs}/static_output.html
```

Static files don't change each time you look at it, making it more dynamicly could be done with crontab.

Comment: thanks sir but i want to execute commands in "textbox" of cgi not in sourse code of cgi ,,

Comment: Not very clear, I edited my answer the way I think you want.

Comment: @saba You didn't mention any textbox in your question. Please click `edit` under your original question and make sure your question asks for exactly what you want, else you waste people's time.